# Is there a way to remove only unknown tags by Imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, exiftool

I see following output when I identify a TIFF file:
TIFF 3426x4378 3426x4378+0+0 1-bit Bilevel Gray 578044B 0.010u 0:00.009
identify: Unknown field with tag 32934 (0x80a6) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/995.

I suppose the "Unknown field with tag 32934" is referring to a EXIF field? Is the unknown field something I can selectively remove via exiftool or imagemagick? I'd like to remove this unknown field to avoid any potential issues it may cause.

Answer (score 2):

Those are just warnings that Imagemagick does not know about certain custom TIFF tags that have nothing to do with Imagemagick processing. You cannot remove them from your file with Imagemagick (though you likely could with Exiftool). However, you can add -quiet to your identify command. That will suppress the display of all those warnings.

So do

```
identify -quiet image.tiff

or 

identify -quiet -verbose image.tiff
```

and they should not show at your terminal.

You can also add them to your convert commands to suppress those warnings.